# Is there an idiom that means that you are set up to be very successful?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means that you are set up to be very successful? If there's no such idiom can you think of an idiom that means something similar related to success or something else? I am thinking of using the idiom in an essay about business success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the idiom:

[have the world by the tail](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+world+by+the+tail)

The idiom means:

> To be very successful, contented, and happy in life.
>
> Samantha landed her dream job after finishing at the top of her class in college. She has the world by the tail!

Also [have the world at your feet](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+world+at+feet)

> have many advantages, and so have many opportunities to choose from; be very successful and admired:
>
> When you’re young you’ve got the world at your feet. She’s got money; she’s well-educated; the world is at her feet.